# Passing a list of components in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am creating a `Row` component in svelte, which can take in any amount of cells.

This works:

```
<Row
  header
  cells={["First", "Second"]}
/>
```

As does this:

```
<Row
  header
  cells={["1", "2", "3", "4"]}
/>
```

But, is there a way I can pass custom components instead of primitive values? The following results in a syntax error (I can do this in JSX):

```
<Row
  header
  cells={[<div />, <button />, <span />]}
/>
```

EDIT:

this is my code for Row

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let cells
  export let widths
  export let header

  const sum = widths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  for (let i = 0; i < widths.length; i++ ){
    console.log(widths[i] / sum * 100)
  }
</script>

<div class="row" class:header>
  {#each cells as cell, i}
    <div class="cell" style={`width: ${widths[i] / sum * 100}%`}>
      { cell }
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with svelte, But for the `component composition` you can use [slots](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "solution" I came up with. Not the best, but will suit my needs.

```js
    <script lang="ts">
      export let cells
      export let widths
      // The amount of cells in the 
      export let header

      const sum = widths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      for (let i = 0; i < widths.length; i++ ){
        console.log(widths[i] / sum * 100)
      }
    </script>

    <div class="row" class:header>
      <!-- 
        The reason this is like this is because Svelte can't handle dynamic slots,
        and doesn't support passing components by reference like in jsx. If we ever need
        more columns, then we can just copy and add more. It's just an unrolled for:
      -->
      {#if widths[0] !== undefined}
        <div class="cell" style={`width: ${widths[0] / sum * 100}%`}>
          <slot name="0"> </slot>
        </div>
      {/if}

      {#if widths[1] !== undefined}
        <div class="cell" style={`width: ${widths[1] / sum * 100}%`}>
          <slot name="1"> </slot>
        </div>
      {/if}

      {#if widths[2] !== undefined}
        <div class="cell" style={`width: ${widths[2] / sum * 100}%`}>
          <slot name="2"> </slot>
        </div>
      {/if}

// And so on...

<style>
  .row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  .cell {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .header {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .cell:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<svelte:component>` tag, but you have to think differently.

image your cell to be defined like this :

```
interface Cell {
  value?: any;
  component?: SvelteComponent;
}
```

then your `Row` can be implemented like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let cells
  export let widths
  export let header

  const sum = widths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  for (let i = 0; i < widths.length; i++ ){
    console.log(widths[i] / sum * 100)
  }
</script>

<div class="row" class:header>
  {#each cells as cell, i}
    <div class="cell" style={`width: ${widths[i] / sum * 100}%`}>
      {#if cell.component}
        <svelte:component this={cell.component} value={cell.value}/>
      {:else}
        {cell.value}
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: How would you use this though? You can't do `<Cell component={<div/>} />`, right